# Understanding noise budget calculation in seal

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

I am trying to understand theory behind [noise budget operation](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/206648d0e4634e5c61dcf9370676630268290b59/native/src/seal/decryptor.cpp#L383) implemented in seal

Let the ciphertext be defined as

$$
    c0=A \in Rq \\c1= As+v+delta*m \in Rq
$$

They first calculate noise polynomial

$$
    c1-c0s = delta*m + v \pmod Q
$$

After that they perform multiply by plaintext mod t

$$
    (Q*m + t v )= tv\pmod Q
$$

After this I am confused because they mentioned in comments

```
// Multiply by plain_modulus and reduce mod coeff_modulus to get coeff_modulus()*noise.
```

For the above step. I am not sure if I am missing something. Will really appreciate if you can also point me to some article that has explain it.

Comment: Could you use $\LaTeX$/MathJax for those equeations?

Comment: Also, your Q missing that you are talking about the decryption.